# Contour plot with positive and negative values

Tags: plotting

I want to make a simple contour plot with a function that takes positive and negative values (see below). I need the absolute values of the function to take the same shade in the contour plot (and greyscale would be best). Ultimately, I want the figure to look like a curved hill, where the top of the hill is the 0 contour.

Also, it would be great if I could remove the defined contour lines and smooth out  the borders of the contours.

Thanks if you can help!

```
ContourPlot[(1 - c N z)/(N z - c N z^2) /. {c -> .01}, {N, 2, 50}, {z,
```

0, 20}]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should avoid using `N` as a variable name as `N` is a reserved word for a function that gives the numerical value of an expression to a desired precision.

The smoothness can be improved by increasing the default number of points used to create the contours (`PlotPoints`).  The color scheme can be changed by the `ColorFunction` option.  To make the level '0' the maximum you'd want to use `-Abs[...]`:

```
ContourPlot[-Abs[(1 - c n z)/(n z - c n z^2) /. {c -> .01}], {n, 2, 50}, {z, 0, 20},
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image: gray scale contour plot]

To show a "hill" it might be better to use `Plot3D`:

```
Show[Plot3D[-Abs[(1 - c n z)/(n z - c n z^2) /. {c -> .01}], {n, 2, 
   50}, {z, 0, 20},
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel],
 Graphics3D[{Red, 
   Line[Table[{n, 1/(c n) /. c -> 0.01, 0}, {n, 5, 50}]]}]]
```

[image: 3D plot with gray scale]

Comment: I think the 3D plot will work best.  Could you please tell me how to add a line to the "hilltop", where the function is zero?  This is 1/(c n).

Comment: @jmbierna Hilltop line added.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) with `ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reversed"}]` as the color function:

```
c =  .01;
DensityPlot[Abs[(1 - c n z)/(n z - c n z^2) ],
  {n, 2, 50}, {z, 0, 20}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reversed"}]]
```

[image]

Using `ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &)` gives a similar picture.